# Display HTML tags inside react-json-tree

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-tree

to display a json tree in react. How do I add an HTML tag as a JSON value. Are

there there any other ways to display HTML tags as JSON.

Currently my array looks like this

```
array : [{
            value:<p>Something</p>
         }]
```

and my JSON tree output shows the output as [JSON display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxldn.png)

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-tree#customize-rendering

Comment: No. I haven't tried that. I am new to Javascript and React. So I am kinda confused on how to the labelrenderer. Is it possible to provide an example ??

Comment: see answer.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom renderer. Details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-tree#customize-rendering)

You could wrap the values with `<p>` that you are expecting. Something like this

```
<JSONTree
   valueRenderer={raw => <p>{raw}</p>}
/>
```

Cheers!